# "unsupported combination of input order" in skcuda linalg

Tags: python, scipy

I am using a manually implemented Neural Network in python. 
I use two numpy arrays X and X_test as the vectors with test samples. One being the training and the other a testing set.

When I pass these through the series of functions I have, everything works swell and I get whatever result I want. 
However, when I slice these vectors to only contain columns(or input features) that I have determined to be relevant to the output, I get the following error:

```
File "/storage/home/abhirathb/BNN/src/Layer.py", line 498, in updateOutputs
  self.outputs = linalg.dot(inputs,self.weights)
File "/home/abhirathb/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skcuda/linalg.py", line 634, in dot
  return add_dot(x_gpu, y_gpu, out, transa, transb, 1.0, 0.0, handle)
File "/home/abhirathb/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skcuda/linalg.py", line 465, in add_dot
  raise ValueError('unsupported combination of input order')
ValueError: unsupported combination of input order
```

Similar errors are thrown if the arrays being supplied to linalg.dot don't have the correct dimensionality. However, I have tested for that and have found nothing wrong. 
Infact, the patch that works to sort this issue out is rather strange. After slicing both the arrays, I merely save them to a file, and load them back. and then this error doesn't show up.

I am unable to figure out what the cause may be and why this patch would work at all. 
Hope someone can point me to the right direction

Comment: Without code and/or concrete input it's not possible to tell what's wrong with the input. Please see how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you use the numpy transpose function, a numpy.ndarray object goes from being C contiguous (which it is by default) to fortran contiguous (or vice-versa). I suspect that the error stems from a problem with contiguity, since 1) basic methods of the GPUArray object often throw up errors relating to contiguity, and 2) the skcuda.linalg functions seem to pass an error like you describe when you pass a transposed array to the gpu and try to do operations on it.

If you're passing a numpy array to the gpu, you can change its contiguity before you pass it using

```
x = numpy.ascontiguousarray(x)
```

for C contiguity, or

```
x = numpy.asfortranarray(x)
```

for fortran contiguity. I don't know if there's any way to change the contiguity of an array once it's on the GPU, but I assume there are appropriate methods in the pycuda.gpyarray module.

Answer (score 0):

The following code reproduces the error:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy as np
import skcuda.linalg as linalg
import skcuda.misc as misc
linalg.init()
a = np.asarray(np.random.rand(4, 2), np.float32)
b = a.transpose()
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(b)
c_gpu = linalg.dot(a_gpu, b_gpu)
np.allclose(np.dot(a, b), c_gpu.get())
```

As described in the post by @z-cris the error can be avoided by using

```
b = a.transpose()
b = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
```